# Angularjs $http.get() not working! what wrong? How can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Help me fix my code. 
I change the port and restart server, it still not works.

```
<div ng-repeat="x in records"> {{x.name}} {{x.email}} {{x.number}}</div>
```

this does not displaying anything

My code here

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http) {    
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "http://localhost:8081/contact"
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log("success");
        $scope.records = response.data;
    }, function errorCallback(response){
        console.log("error");
    })
});
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting? please check in developer tool (network tab)

Comment: What is not displaying? the console or the records?

Comment: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:4231/contact. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Is your AngularJS site on localhost:4231? If not, this is happening because of the [same-origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Comment: @Mamun: the records is not displaying

Comment: What is console.log(respone) in success callback?

Answer (score 0):

The **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** response header indicates whether the response can be shared with resources with the given origin.

So your back end Web service should include your origin (In this example http://localhost:4231) in it's response in Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. Otherwise it will not share the requested resource.

Syntax of setting this header as below

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
OR
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: <origin>
```

Comment: thanks, it works :)

Comment: Welcome. It's my pleasure.